# Manipulating audio in AVI files

Tags: audio, video, editing, avi

I'm looking to perform basic sound editing operations (applying low/high pass filters, eq, etc - to get rid of some annoying background buzz) to the audio in an AVI. Anyone familiar with any free or at least cheap tools that can achieve this?

(Windows, POSIX, hell.. VAX if you like)

(PS. Alternatively a software library that can do it would work as well, language doesn't matter. Unless it's VB... anything but VB)

Comment: I believe that VirtualDub can do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't find any. Using Adobe Premiere to split the audio from the AVI and then using my music studio to modify it before passing it back in.

Answer (score 1):

Virtual Dub Maybe can do it, quite a few options

http://www.videohelp.com/download/VirtualDubMod_1_5_10_2_b2542.zip

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.